# How to delegate to many functions from a single function in Python?

Tags: python

I need to run many commands on a system over multiple nodes in Python.  I want each node to run independently so I figured that I would make a class for each node and fill it with methods that are specific to nodes.  But when writing my algorithm to make use of those methods, I find that I have to put every call in a for loop:

```
class MultipleThings(object):
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index

    def some_function(self):
        print "I am index ", self.index

class CollectionOfThings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_objects = []
        for index in range(5):
            self.list_of_objects.append(MultipleThings(index))

        for thing in self.list_of_objects:     # Yuck!!
            thing.some_function()

main = CollectionOfThings()
```

This code works perfectly and gives me 5 print statements.  But it is ugly and tedious.  How can I get rid of "for thing in self.list_of_objects:" and just call self.some_function() once, then perhaps let a decorator do the for loop to all of the thing's that exist in my list of things?

Edit:  I guess you could consider this a "batch" mode?  For example, I want to run "ls -l" on 10 systems, then let each class instance process those commands.  When they are all done, the next command might be to "rm tmp" on all 10 systems, and so on.  Multiprocessing will be needed as well, so that the for loop doesn't block on each node.

Comment: I do not really get your point. What is so ugly about the for-loop? Do you want a one-liner? Then use `map(lambda thing: thing.some_function(), self.list_of_objects)`

If your question has some other deeper motivation, like design-principles or something, please clarify this.

Comment: Let's say I have 50 steps to process on a node, it would mean 50 for loops for each step.  So for node in nodes: run_cmd("ls -l), etc.  Since I know I want to run this same command on all nodes before moving to the rm step, there should be a way to batch them up?

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that you have 50 different functions, and you want to call all of them on all 10 elements of the list, and you don't want to write 50 `for` loops, right?

Comment: @abarnert  Yes, exactly.  I am hoping for a very readable single call, that when called will distribute to 10 different instances.

Comment: @DavidLynch: OK, I gave you a few different options to do that in an answer—both how to replace each `for` loop with a more readable single call, and how to replace _all_ of the calls with a bigger `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this does what you want or not:

```
class CollectionOfThings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_objects = []
        self.list_of_objects = [MultipleThings(index) for index in range(5)]
        self.callFunc(self.list_of_objects, "some_function")

    def callFunc(self, items, func, *args, **kwargs):
        for thing in items:
            getattr(thing, func)(*args, **kwargs)
```

As @Thorsten points out, simply using `map` with a `lambda` is a way to do what you are trying to do.  My attempt was to make a general solution.

You could pass the function itself like so to avoid passing a string argument.

```
class CollectionOfThings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_objects = []
        self.list_of_objects = [MultipleThings(index) for index in range(5)]
        self.callFunc(self.list_of_objects, MultipleThings.some_function)

    def callFunc(self, items, func, *args, **kwargs):
        for thing in items:
            func(thing, *args, **kwargs)
```

This returns both a list and dict:

```
class MultipleThings(object):
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index

    def some_function(self, key, value):
        return "I am index %s with key %s and value %s" % (self.index, key, value)

class CollectionOfThings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_objects = []
        self.list_of_objects = [MultipleThings(index) for index in range(5)]
        retList, retDict = self.callFunc(self.list_of_objects, MultipleThings.some_function, "foo", value="bar")
        print retList, retDict

    def callFunc(self, items, func, *args, **kwargs):
        retList = []
        retDict = {}
        for i, thing in enumerate(items):
            funcReturn = func(thing, *args, **kwargs)
            retList.append(funcReturn)
            retDict[i] = funcReturn

        return retList, retDict
```

Comment: Good catch adding the *args, **kwargs on there... I should have included an input with my example.  How would I use that in the call to callFunc?  I was hoping to avoid putting the name of the function in a string, but this is better than the for loop...

Comment: Just saw the second part of your answer...how would I add parameters to some_function in the call to callFunc?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use those arguments.  Are they the same for each call to `some_function`, or unique for each instance of `MultipleThings`?

Comment: They are the same to each call to some_function, and I should have added a return value to my example as well!

Comment: What would you expect the returned value from `callFunc` to look?  A dictionary of `index: returnVal`, a list of return values?

Comment: @DavidLynch: There _is_ a way to avoid passing the function by string, if the methods are actually defined in some common class of all of the things. It's hard to explain in a comment, so I wrote it as an answer (although sberry will probably get it immediately if I say "unbound method").

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  You can code faster than I can read!  I was thinking of just exit status, but I didn't consider multiple return values, so you have given me something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a `list` of, say, 10 items, and then you want to run 50 functions on each item in the `list`, and you don't want to have to write 50 `for` loops.

One possibility is to write a function that wraps that up:

```
def apply(method, seq):
    for item in seq:
        method(item)
```

Then, instead of this:

```
for thing in self.list_of_objects:     # Yuck!!
    thing.some_function()
for thing in self.list_of_objects:     # Yuck!!
    thing.other_function()
for thing in self.list_of_objects:     # Yuck!!
    thing.third_function()
# ... 47 more times
```

You can do this:

```
apply(ThingClass.some_function, self.list_of_objects)
apply(ThingClass.other_function, self.list_of_objects)
apply(ThingClass.third_function, self.list_of_objects)
# ... 47 more times
```

Functions and methods are first-class objects in Python, just like anything else, so you can pass them around to other functions easily. Of course `first_thing.some_function` and `second_thing.some_function` are actually different bound methods; the trick is that you can get the unbound method from the class, and then pass it the object as an explicit `self` parameter. (Try printing out `first_thing.some_function`, `ThingClass.some_function`, `type(first_thing.some_function)`, and `type(ThingClass.some_function)`, and playing with them in the interactive interpreter.)

This assumes, of course, that the reason all of these items have the same methods is that they're instances of the same class. If that's not true, and you're relying on duck typing instead, then you need something slightly different:

```
def apply(methodname, seq):
    for item in seq:
        getattr(item, methodname)()

apply('some_function', self.list_of_objects)
# ... 49 more times
```

Here, the trick is the `getattr` function, which lets you get any method or member by name at runtime.

But if you think about it, what you really want here is to iterate over those 50 unbound methods or names, and not have to repeat yourself at all. For example:

```
for name in ('some_function', 'other_function', 'third_function',
             # ... 47 more names
            ):
    for obj in self.list_of_objects:
        getattr(obj, name)()
```

Note that the first version of the `apply` method could just as easily be replaced by the built-in `map` (only in Python 2.x, not 3.x), or even a list comprehension. However, there are some reasons not do to that:

- It's generally considered questionable style to use `map` or a comprehension when you're only calling the function for its side-effects.
- If you have a *lot* of items, instead of just 50*10, it wastes memory and time building up `list`s of results that you don't need.
- In Python 3, `map` returns an iterator instead of a `list`, so it won't actually perform the functions at all unless you iterate over it somehow. (You're obviously using 2.x today, because of your `print` statements, but presumably one day you will switch to 3.x.)

You can solve those problems by using `itertools.imap` (or a generator expression) instead of `map` (or a list comprehension) and disposing of the iterable by, e.g., feeding it into a 0-sized `deque`. But at that point, it's not exactly clear what your code is doing.

Meanwhile, writing the function explicitly means it's easy to modify into, e.g., the second version when you discover you need to.

Comment: Your `apply`-method is exactly the built-in `map` - just ignore the return value of map.

Comment: @ThorstenKranz: Did you not understand the last paragraph, or just not bother to read it? If it needs to be rewritten to be clearer, please tell me what to fix.

Comment: I've edited it to hopefully explain more clearly why you may not want to use `map`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I didn't really notice it. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: @ThorstenKranz: No problem. Because you raised the issue, I (hopefully) addressed it better; if so, everyone wins.